# Python: from .txt file into sql table

Tags: python, sql

I have a text file which contains certain amount of hours in format 'hh:mm' and in order like this below:

Times1.txt:

```
10:12 13:22 15:45 18:23 19:20(...)
```

Now I would like to import this .txt file to SQL database named Times1.db by using **Python and SQLite3**, and create a table with one column and each row of this column will be next hour, like this:

```
10:12
13:22
15:45
18:23
19:20
(...)
```

So I can get from this table for example only second row which will be 13:22.

If this may change something .txt file may store this hours in this format as well:

```
10:12,12:22,15:45,(...)
```

or

```
10:12
12:22
15:45
(...)
```

I tried to do this in many ways but all I can get is single row with all hours in it.

This is what I tried this far:

```
import os
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

#c.execute("CREATE TABLE time(hour REAL)")
#table time is already created

#thanks to @Asav Patel
with open('test.txt') as f1:
    hours = next(f1).split()

for hour in hours:
    print (hour)    

c.executemany("INSERT INTO time (hour) VALUES (?)", (hour,))

conn.commit()

def read_from_database():
    sql = "SELECT * FROM time"

    for row in c.execute(sql):
        print(row)
        print(row[0])

read_from_database()

conn.close()
```

Comment: May I see you what you did so far ?

Comment: @orvi I posted what I have so far

Answer (score 0):

assuming there's only one line in your file.

```
with open('test_docs/file1.txt') as f:
    hours = f.read().split()

for hour in hours:
    print (hour)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay. This is working, but how I can import this split text into SQL database so it's give each hour a new row in column?

Comment: you have to generate a SQL statement with each hour and write it to another file then import that file in database

Answer (score -1):

Ok guys, I found a way to do this :) I tested it and it's working.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE example(Time REAL)")

num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('test.txt'))
f=open('test.txt')
lines=f.readlines()
i=1
while True:
    time = (lines[i])
    c.execute("INSERT INTO example (Time) VALUES (?)", (time, ))
    conn.commit()
    i+=1
    if i == num_lines:
        break

conn.close()
```

@cwallenpoole

But this is only way I found to create a table like this:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os6e6.jpg)

Comment: @cwallenpoole do you know better way to crate a table like I posted in my comment above?